# Polar coordinates: fixing ratio between arc and radius

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

When drawing a coordinate system with fixed step size, the standard polar coordinates

$$
x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)
$$

exhibits stretched pixels for large $r$. Ignoring the singularity in $(0,0)$, is it possible to construct a similar coordinate system where which preserves the ratio $rd\theta:dr$ when changing $r$.